# How to find the products expiring within the weekend of the current week?

Tags: sql

How to find the products expiring within the weekend of the current week?

Say we have Products table including (id, name, production_date, shelf_age)

Example:
Say today is 27/11/2020

“Product X” production_date is 8/11/2020 and its shelf_age is 20 days so its expiry is 28/11/2020 which is a weekend day of this week.

“Product Y” production_date is 7/11/2020 and its shelf_age is 20 days so its expiry is 27/11/2020 which is a working day of this week.

Product X need to be included in the result but Y should be excluded.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work i think:

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE 
DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(d,shelf_age,production_date) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
AND DATEDIFF(d,DATEADD(d,shelf_age,production_date),GETDATE()) < 7
AND DATEDIFF(d,DATEADD(d,shelf_age,production_date),GETDATE()) >= 0
```

As you can see you can use `DATENAME()` function to get the name of the day to filter weekdays.
Might be some polishing needed as next clause i have here is <7 which means that if you run a query on Sunday or Saturday it will give you next Sunday and Saturday, but you can play with that.